# Баг в игре Тетрис

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, консоль

Делаю игру Тетрис в консоли. Когда блок падает в угле или впритык к другому блоку, то он просто проваливается. Я предполагаю, что проблема в методе if_border.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

#define WIDTH 30
#define HEIGHT 30

class block
{
public:
    block()
    {
        this->x = -100;
        this->y = -100;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                this->texture[i][j] = 0;
                this->texture[3][0] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    static int BLOCK_COUNTER;
    static char skin;
    static char border;

    int texture[4][4];

    int x, y;
    void control(char[HEIGHT][WIDTH]);
    int if_border(char[HEIGHT][WIDTH]);
    void next_block();
};

class other
{
public:
    static void fill_map(char[HEIGHT][WIDTH]);
    static void display(char[HEIGHT][WIDTH]);
    static void SetCur();
    static void replace_block(block *, int);
};

int block::BLOCK_COUNTER = 0;
char block::skin = '0';
char block::border = '#';

block b[87];

int main()
{
    char gmap[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    b[0].x = WIDTH / 2;
    b[0].y = -1;
    for (int k = 0; k < 80; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                b[k].texture[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    /*for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    {
        other::replace_block(&b[0], 0);
    }
    other::replace_block(&b[0], 0);*/

    b[0].texture[2][0] = 1;
    b[0].texture[2][1] = 1;
    b[0].texture[3][0] = 1;
    b[0].texture[3][1] = 1;

    while (true)
    {
        if (block::BLOCK_COUNTER > 80)
        {
            exit(1);
        }
        other::fill_map(gmap);
        b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].control(gmap);
        other::display(gmap);
        cout << "Colision:    " << b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) << endl;
        cout << "BLOCK COUNTER:    " << block::BLOCK_COUNTER << endl;
        cout << "X:    " << b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].x << endl;
        cout << "Y:    " << b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].y << endl;
        other::SetCur();
        if ((b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 30)
        && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 31)
        && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 32)
        && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 33))
        {
            b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].y++;
        }
        if (GetKeyState('P') < 0)
            system("pause");
        //Sleep(300);
        //system("pause");
    }


    return 0;
}

void other::fill_map(char gmap[HEIGHT][WIDTH])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0
                || i == HEIGHT - 1 || j == WIDTH - 1)
            {
                gmap[i][j] = block::border;
            }
            else
            {
                gmap[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < block::BLOCK_COUNTER + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                if (b[i].texture[i][j])
                {
                    gmap[b[i].y + j][b[i].x - k] = block::skin;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //gmap[15][15] = '@';
}

void other::display(char gmap[HEIGHT][WIDTH])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
        {
            cout << gmap[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void other::SetCur()
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = 0;
    coord.Y = 0;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

void block::control(char gmap[HEIGHT][WIDTH])
{
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_LEFT) < 0) && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 10)
    && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 11)
    && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 12)
    && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 13))
    {
        b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].x--;
    }
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_RIGHT) < 0) && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 20)
    && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 21)
    && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 22)
    && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 23))
    {
        b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].x++;
    }
    if (GetKeyState(VK_UP) < 0)
    {
        b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].y--;
    }
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) < 0) && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 30)
    && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 31)
    && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 32)
    && (b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].if_border(gmap) != 33))
    {
        b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].y++;
    }
}

int block::if_border(char gmap[HEIGHT][WIDTH])
{
    if (gmap[this->y][this->x - 4] != ' ')
    {
        return 10;
    }
    else if (gmap[this->y + 1][this->x - 4] != ' ')
    {
        return 11;
    }
    else if (gmap[this->y + 2][this->x - 4] != ' ')
    {
        return 12;
    }
    else if (gmap[this->y + 3][this->x - 4] != ' ')
    {
        return 13;
    }

    else if (gmap[this->y][this->x + 1] != ' ')
    {
        return 20;
    }
    else if (gmap[this->y + 1][this->x + 1] != ' ')
    {
        return 21;
    }
    else if (gmap[this->y + 2][this->x + 1] != ' ')
    {
        return 22;
    }
    else if (gmap[this->y + 3][this->x + 1] != ' ')
    {
        return 23;
    }

    else if (gmap[this->y + 4][this->x - 3] != ' ')
    {
        next_block();
        return 30;
    }
    else if (gmap[this->y + 4][this->x - 2] != ' ')
    {
        next_block();
        return 31;
    }
    else if (gmap[this->y + 4][this->x - 1] != ' ')
    {
        next_block();
        return 32;
    }
    else if (gmap[this->y + 4][this->x] != ' ')
    {
        next_block();
        return 33;
    }
    else if (gmap[this->y + 4][this->x + 2] != ' ')
    {
        next_block();
        return 34;
    }

    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
void block::next_block()
{
    block::BLOCK_COUNTER++;
    b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].x = WIDTH / 2;
    b[block::BLOCK_COUNTER].y = 5;
    cout << '\a';
}

void other::replace_block(block *b, int num)
{
    switch(num)
    {
    case 0:
        b->texture[2][0] = 1;
        b->texture[2][1] = 1;
        b->texture[3][0] = 1;
        b->texture[3][1] = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше всех вашу программу знаете только вы. Берёте в одну руку отладчик, в другую точки останова, отладочный вывод, assert'ы, и начинаете _отлаживать программу_. Тщательно следите за состоянием объектов программы. Рассчитываете в уме/на калькуляторе/на бумаге какие значения переменных должны быть, какие есть и почему не совпадают. Если потребуется, выполняйте программу пошагово с первой строки в функции `main`. 278 строк исходного кода... надеяться, что кто-то сделает это за вас — так себе затея. Конечно, может кто и возьмётся вам помочь — чудеса случаются от случая к случаю.

Comment: @wololo Спасибо за ответ! Буду учится пользоваться отладчиком.

Comment: @AlexeyTugalov - основная беда вашего кода - стены из копипасты. 
1) при их формировании, вы наверняка несколько раз ошиблись
2) пытаться это "распарсить" и понять, что ваша программа делает (и что вы на самом деле хотели сделать) - как видите, за рабочий день желающих не нашлось.

Comment: @gbg да я и так уже решил этот баг) Всем спасибо!